# React add JSX to variables in map every loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, conditional-statements

Hi i have an array which i want to map only once and i wonder if i can do something like this:

```
  let markersResult;
  let polylines;

  markers.map((marker, index: number) => {
    const nextMarker = markers[index + 1];

    markersResult += (
      <UserMapMarker key={String(index)} marker={marker} />
    )

    if (nextMarker && marker.alertsStatus === nextMarker.alertsStatus ) {
      polylines += (
        <p>polyline</p>
      )
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      {markersResult}
      <div>
        {polylines}
      </div>
    </>
  )
```

It is important to me to use solution similar to that because i have to check if marker has the same value as next marker in loop and then do something with polylines

Comment: {polylines.map(poly=>poly)} make markersResult and polylines as array and push values into them

Comment: Can you write a simple example?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?